# Why does 108 + 2x = 180 in this problem?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, angle

Here is the question of interest, along with the solution:

[ AMC Year 9 Intermediate Test Paper Question 3][image: 1]

I fully understand the question and its requirements. But what I don't understand is the solution. On the sixth line of the solution, it says $108 + 2x = 180$. I do not understand how this is equal to $180$. It's probably a simple case of angle mathematics but I am struggling to figure it out.

A reason why $108 + 2x$ is equal to $180$ in this case would be sufficient.

Thank you,

Comment: In the triangle $\triangle QOT$, $\angle QOT+ \angle OQT+\angle  OTQ=180^{\circ}$ by the [angle sum property of a triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_angles_of_a_triangle).

Comment: As is pointed out in the solution, the ten angles $\angle QOR, \angle ROS, \angle SOT, ..., \angle ZOQ$ are all equal to $360/10=36$ because the points are equally spaced out. Then $\angle QOT = \angle QOR + \angle ROS + \angle SOT=3\times 36=108$. Since the sum of the internal angles of a triangle is $180$, we can form the equation $2x+108=180$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the internal angles in any triangle is $180^\circ$.

There is more information in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_angles_of_a_triangle).

Comment: OMDS Thank you so much what a silly question

Comment: @ajray89 Don't worry, you are doing well, keep going.